# I have an error showing a fullcalendar inside a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, bootstrap-5

hi im trying to set a fullcalendar inside a bootstrap modal but it shows itself comprimed at the top-left corner and i cant see anything, but when i resize the screen it changes and shows perfect, and i dont know why, i also tried doing it outside of the modal and it works perfects, do any of you have a hint about the problem?

[before resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvxCQ.png)
[after rsize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVJ37.png)

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="calendarModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Holidays</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="closeCalendarModal">
                            <i class="bi bi-x-lg"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="calendar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            $(".calendarmodal").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
                });
                calendar.setOption('locale', 'es');
                calendar.render();

                $("#calendarModal").modal("toggle");

            });
});
```

```
#calendarModal .modal-dialog {
            max-width: 70%;
            /* Ajusta el ancho máximo según tus necesidades */
        }

        #calendarModal .modal-content {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            max-height: 80vh;
            /* Ajusta la altura máxima según tus necesidades */
        }
```

i tried putting outside and inside the modal, applied css styles and initializing with javascript and jquery

Comment: My guess would be that the calendar is initialised before the modal is displayed and therefore cannot calculate the available space. Have you tried using the modal `shown.bs.modal`  event to initialise the calendar after the modal is visible to the user?

Comment: @fubar yes i tried that too but it didnt work

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a code snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: `$('#calendarModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   calendar.render();
});` should be the general idea. Make sure `calendar` is in scope at that point, of course

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering the calendar (calendar.render()) before the modal is visible.

I don't usually work with Bootstrap but if you read the documentation on the modal, you can see there is an event called 'shown.bs.modal' that is triggered when the modal has been shown to the user.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {})
```

So I would suggest your code to first call the modal and once the modal is displayed render the calendar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        $(".calendarmodal").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#calendarModal").modal("toggle");

        })
});

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
    });
    calendar.setOption('locale', 'es');
    calendar.render();
})
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Yes, although it might be better to initialise the calendar once, beforehand, and then call `calendar.render();` during the modal shown event, then it doesn't destroy any changes, or cause unnecessary requests to fetch event data etc.

Comment: I Agree. If can easily become "why doesn't this work" rabbit hunt or a performance bottleneck.

Just want to contribute with 2 more cents for less experienced developers. 

This is a "every case is it's own case" situation. Meaning you need to evaluate if the calendar has information it needs before the modal is shown or if there is necessary information that is only available or should only be fetched after the modal is shown.

Comment: Even without the argument about extra data, it would still be more efficient to initialise the calendar only once. If it's necessary to re-fetch data, the refetchEvents command can be used, specifically.

Answer (score 1):

See the working example : https://jsfiddle.net/Arzeb/x8ogfkd0/1/

Looks like your code is fine but Calendar is rendered before the modal open and height occupied by the modal body

**Use `shown.bs.modal` event of bs modal and add option of `height: 700` to the calendar**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    $(".calendarmodal").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#calendarModal").modal("show");
    });
    
    var myModal = document.getElementById('calendarModal');

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        height: 700
    });
    
    myModal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        calendar.render();
    });
});
```

*Let me know if it's helped you*

Comment: Yes, although it might be better to initialise the calendar once, beforehand, and then call only `calendar.render();` during the modal shown event, then it doesn't destroy any changes, or cause unnecessary requests to fetch event data etc.

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm gonna change that to initialize only once.

Answer (score -1):

add set time out:

```
const button = document.getElementById("button");
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                ...
                });
                setTimeout(() => {
                    calendar.render();
                }, "500");;
            });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).